# .Net Console app - Merging Multiple Excel Sheet into Single Sheet throwing 'Out of Memory' Error

Tags: c#, .net, excel, console-application

Trying to Merge data from Multiple Excel sheets of single excel workbook into single sheet. Each excel sheet is having 50k rows and around 80 columns. Application is throwing 'Out of Memory' Exception as data is huge.

Code:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(InputExcelFilePath, false))
{
WorkbookPart wbPart = doc.WorkbookPart;
Sheet mainRosterSheet = wbPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == "TestSheet").FirstOrDefault();
Worksheet mainWorksheet = ((WorksheetPart)wbPart.GetPartById(mainRosterSheet.Id)).Worksheet;
SheetData mainSheetdata = (SheetData)mainWorksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
Sheets sheetcollection = wbPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();

foreach (Sheet childSheet in sheetcollection)
{
    string sheetName = childSheet.Name;
    if (sheetName.StartsWith("TestSheet ("))
    {
        Worksheet childWorksheet = ((WorksheetPart)wbPart.GetPartById(childSheet.Id)).Worksheet;
        SheetData childsheetdata = (SheetData)childWorksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>(); //Thowing Out of Meory Exception
    }
}
}
```

Using OpenXML library for excel operations.
Please suggest if any helper library that can be used to merge excel sheets with huge data, if data size is limitation with above approach.

Comment: Buying another stick of RAM is probably cheaper than a developer even having a requirements meeting. Sometimes, hardware *is* the solution.

Comment: Project > Properties > Build tab, untick "Prefer 32-bit".  You don't prefer it.

Comment: @HansPassant Setting "Prefer 32-bit" solved the memory issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest that instead of doing it on a single bulk operation, that you do it one by one, disposing so you can free-up some memory... something like:

```
WorkbookPart wbPart = doc.WorkbookPart;
Sheet mainRosterSheet = wbPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == "TestSheet").FirstOrDefault();
Worksheet mainWorksheet = ((WorksheetPart)wbPart.GetPartById(mainRosterSheet.Id)).Worksheet;
SheetData mainSheetdata = (SheetData)mainWorksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
Sheets sheetcollection = wbPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();

foreach (Sheet childSheet in sheetcollection)
{
using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(InputExcelFilePath, false))
{
string sheetName = childSheet.Name;
if (sheetName.StartsWith("TestSheet ("))
{
    Worksheet childWorksheet = ((WorksheetPart)wbPart.GetPartById(childSheet.Id)).Worksheet;
    SheetData childsheetdata = (SheetData)childWorksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>(); //Thowing Out of Meory Exception
}
}
}
```

Code above was not tested

Comment: Thank you for response. I will try this.